# Android Action Bar Menu Item Title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, appbar, android-titlebar

Why does not show the action_call.title in the second device ??
I want to show the action_call.title on each device.

this device Android 5.1.1 (api22) 7"

[image]

this device Android 6.0 (api23) 5.96"

[image]

this is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_call"
    android:icon="@drawable/call"
    android:title="@string/action_call"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_info"
    android:icon="@drawable/info2"
    android:title="@string/action_info"
    app:showAsAction="never|withText" />


</menu>
```

this is my onCreateOptionsMenu on MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem action_call = menu.findItem(R.id.action_call);

    action_call.setTitle("+99");
    return true;
}
```